# What does it mean that `toString` gets “ignored” if it returns a non-primitive?

Tags: javascript

The [MDN documentation on `Object.prototype.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#overriding_the_default_tostring_method) says that when `toString` gets overriden, it should only return a primitive value:

> The `toString()` function you create must return a primitive, otherwise it will be ignored.

However, in the following example we return an object inside of `toString` and it returns the object normally:

```js
const ob2 = {
    val1: 100,
    val2: 200,
    toString: function() {
      return {
        veh: "meh"
      }; // Object.
    }
  };

console.log(ob2.toString());
```

Output:

```js
{ veh: "meh" }
```

So the `toString` method returns the object normally. What is up with the misinformation?

Comment: [The spec](//tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) uses `toString` in places where it’s called implicitly (which is the way `toString` is normally intended be used), like in `String(ob2)`. I can’t find a requirement that this method shall return a primitive when called explicitly, but I’ll look into older specs. The docs you linked says _“otherwise it will be ignored”_. `String(ob2)` throws a TypeError. So it’s wrong in two regards. Fortunately, it can be [edited via a PR](//github.com/mdn/content/blob/main/files/en-us/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/object/tostring/index.md).

Comment: The tutorial is refering to constructable objects (class like structures) and those have to have a toString method that returns a string. Tried it out and is totally correct that the toString method of constructable objects has to return a string.

Comment: @Palladium02 So toString() shall ONLY return a primitive if it's from an instance of a constructor? This does not apply to other objects.

Comment: @Palladium02 No, even when using `toString` on prototypes of constructors, it works the same way. How exactly have you tried it? The tutorial is also not specifically talking about constructable objects; they just happen to be a useful example there.

Comment: @Palladium02 [I cannot reproduce it](https://jsbin.com/dixewam/edit?js,console)

Comment: @SebastianSimon & VLAZ Tried it in the Chrome console by exactly typing what was given in the tutorial and inspected the resulting constructable object in the console and if the toString method was not returning a string it was ignored and replaced it with the standart one that returns [Object object].

Comment: @SebastianSimon I checked ES5 and there is not really a requirement for it to return a primitive. The only thing I see is in the section for converting a value to a primitive: `toString()` will be tried first and if it returns a non-primitive, then `.valueOf()` would be used on the original value. If *that* returns a non-primitie, then it throws a TypeError. But I don't see anything about ignoring `toString()` exactly. I think MDN means that `toString()` will be ignored in automatic conversions, not in general.

Comment: @Palladium02 I did the same thing and I can’t reproduce this behavior. Here’s the code: `function Dog(name, breed, color, sex){ this.name = name; this.breed = breed; this.color = color; this.sex = sex; } Dog.prototype.toString = function dogToString() { return { a: 1 }; }; const theDog = new Dog('Gabby', 'Lab', 'chocolate', 'female'); console.log(theDog.toString(), "is an object"); console.log(String(theDog), "throws a TypeError");`. Your turn.

Comment: @Palladium02 the code doesn't specify a `toString()`, so if you call it you get the default behaviour. If you override the `toString()` with one that returns an object, it's not "ignored". The later examples *do* specify a `toString()` but they return strings.

Comment: Okay, now we’re getting somewhere! `String(new class{ toString(){ return { a: 1 }; } valueOf(){ return "2"; } })` is `"2"`, but `String(new class{ toString(){ return "1"; } valueOf(){ return "2"; } })` is `"1"`. Now, “ignored” makes sense.

Comment: So, I guess it's just "will be ignored *when automatically converting*". So, it's correct, just doesn't describe the behaviour fully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You’re right, the documentation was misleading and incomplete.
I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/13174) that rewords it as follows:

Removed this part:

> <del>The `toString()` function you create must return a primitive, otherwise it will be ignored.</del>

Replaced by:

> The `toString()` function you create must return a primitive. If it returns an object and the method is called implicitly (i.e. during type conversion or coercion), then its result will be ignored and the value of a related method, [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/valueOf), will be used instead, or a `TypeError` will be thrown if none of these methods return a primitive.

---

I have found the original [pull request](https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/11739#discussion_r778562255) and [commit](https://github.com/mdn/content/commit/8622152c7c8babc78b1b67878bb066127ca28e12) that added this wording.
There is a review comment by the author in reference to this sentence which says:

> See step 5.B.ii from https://262.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive

What the author was referring to is the consequence of the [OrdinaryToPrimitive](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinarytoprimitive) abstract operation in the specification: leaving [`Symbol.toPrimitive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toPrimitive) aside, when a value is coerced to a primitive, the two methods `toString` and `valueOf` (the *methodNames*) are prepared to be called in a specific order based on a type hint.
And then:

> 3. For each element *name* of *methodNames*, do
>
>    1. Let *method* be ? [Get](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-get-o-p)(*O*, *name*).
>    2. If [IsCallable](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-iscallable)(*method*) is **true**, then
>
>       1. Let *result* be ? [Call](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-call)(*method*, *O*).
>       2. If [Type](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ecmascript-data-types-and-values)(result) is not Object, return *result*.

This step is a loop, iterating over the list of *methodNames*.
It takes the next *method* from this list, checks if it is a function, calls it, and stores its result in *result*.
Then it performs the type check.
If the result is a primitive, i.e. not an object, this result is returned.
Otherwise, **the loop continues, effectively ignoring the result**.

If the loop reaches the end without returning a value, a TypeError will be thrown.

In order to demonstrate this behavior, you have to have *both* methods:

```js
class Test1 {
  toString() {
    return "1";
  }
  valueOf() {
    return "2";
  }
}

class Test2 {
  toString() {
    return {};
  }
  valueOf() {
    return "2";
  }
}

class Test3 {
  toString() {
    return "1";
  }
  valueOf() {
    return {};
  }
}

class Test4 {
  toString() {
    return {};
  }
  valueOf() {
    return {};
  }
}

const test1 = new Test1,
  test2 = new Test2,
  test3 = new Test3,
  test4 = new Test4;

console.log(String(test1)); // "1"; toString is preferred.
// `"" + test1` and `+test1` also demonstrate this.
console.log(Number(test1)); // 2; valueOf is preferred.
console.log(String(test2)); // "2"; toString is ignored; valueOf is chosen instead.
console.log(Number(test2)); // 2; valueOf is preferred.
console.log(String(test3)); // "1"; toString is preferred.
console.log(Number(test3)); // 1; valueOf is ignored; toString is chosen instead.
console.log(String(test4)); // TypeError; none of the methods returns a primitive.
console.log(Number(test4)); // TypeError; none of the methods returns a primitive.
```

---

What the documentation *didn’t* refer to was **explicitly** calling the `toString` method, because that works just fine:

```js
class Test {
  toString() {
    return {
      hello: "world"
    };
  }
}

const test = new Test;

console.log(test.toString()); // Logs { hello: "world" }.
```

Comment: Author may have also been confused with `get [Symbol.toStringTag]` and doing `'' + foo` - where a non-string will give back `[object Object]` and a string will give back `[object Foo]`

Comment: @PaulS. Interesting thought, but I was able to confirm that the author did in fact refer to the OrdinaryToPrimitive loop; see the edited answer: I found the original PR.